# Main function usage

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand usage of Main function in C#.
I am trying to write separate method (ex. Method1) to do the action such as:
Asking question to user (what is your name).. return some response ("Glad to meet you, XXX").

I want to put all the functionality such as Asking question and returning response on a separate method (Method1) instead of using Main.

Then, how can I pass step from Main (starting position) to go to that Method1?
I guess my question is how do I call Method1 from Main?
What kind of information do I have in Main method then?

Do I just put like this way?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Method1();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. You'd just make your `Main` method call `Method1`...

Comment: Well Main is your entry-point. From there you decide what your program is doing next. For that you can simply create a method (`Method1`) and call it in your main with `Method1();`. But I don't really get the problem

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I guess my question is how do I call Method1 from Main and what is usage of Main in C# if this type of functionality can be used in a separate function such as Method1 instead of Main? Thank you for your response.

Comment: Just change the signature of your function to start with static to be called from main then but it in main Method();

Answer (score 3):

The Main function in C# is what's known as the **entry point** of your program. If your program was a book and the computer wanted to start reading it, it has to begin from somewhere - that's where Main comes in. It's the method that gets called to get your program going.

As you might have noticed, main is a *static* method:

```
public static void Main(){
    // Your code here
}
```

Without going into too much detail, a static method can only call other static methods, or create an instance of something. So if you wanted Main to call something else, the two options are like this:

```
public static void Main(){
    Method1();
}

// Method1 is also static:

public static void Method1(){
    Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
}
```

Or alternatively by creating an instance:

```
public class MyProgram{

    public static void Main(){
        // Create an instance of this class:
        MyProgram program=new MyProgram();

        // And call Method1 on the instance:
        program.Method1();
    }

    // Notice how method1 is not static this time:
    public void Method1(){
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
    }

}
```